# Harry Potter characters named after places?

Tags: harry-potter, names

I've noticed a few characters in the *Harry Potter* series who share their names with towns in England:

- [Professor Flitwick](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Filius_Flitwick); the Bedfordshire town of [Flitwick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flitwick)
- [Dawlish the Auror](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/John_Dawlish); the Devon town of [Dawlish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawlish)
- [Albert Runcorn](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Albert_Runcorn); the Cheshire town of [Runcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runcorn)

### Is there a list of all Harry Potter characters named after places?

**Bonus question:** has JK Rowling ever commented on why certain characters were named after places, or what about those places inspired her to use their names?

Comment: There's a full character listing here. Go crazy; http://magical-menagerie.com/wizardry/full-character-listing/

Comment: @Richard Also [here](http://www.mugglenet.com/books/name-origins/). But if you do the work of picking out the place-name characters and turning that list into an answer, there's a bunch of rep and a green tick in it for you :-)

Comment: Being named after the place your family comes from is fairly common across Europe, as is being named after a job (Potter, Smith, Baker etc)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - True, but it's a lot of work to prove that quite a lot of her characters, intentionally or not, have names that happen to be places. Was Caradoc Dearborn named after Dearborn, California? Was Daedelus Diggle named after Diggle, Manchester? Who the hell knows and does naming all of the people that are named after places get us any closer to knowing?

Comment: For the record, the *bonus question* seems far and away the most interesting part of this question.

Comment: How can we tell which came first, a Family Name or Town Name? Two of the towns I have lived in were named after the people who founded them. Granted I am in the US so town names are much newer relative to the UK

Comment: @Skooba In real life, sure. But I'm talking about the **out-of-universe** origins of these fictional names.

Comment: there could be an element of coincidence here, and I don't know how you would get a complete answer without "word of god" clarification. Lots of surnames *come from place names*. So a surname being the same as a town doesn't necessarily mean *the character is "named after" the place*.  E.g. Snape and Trelawney (as touched upon below) are both surnames that came from places.

Comment: @Skooba as you implied, the US does things differently. In the UK the place names would generally come first, and lots of people took a place as their surname, when surnames became common.

Comment: A great part of this has got to be that she named hundreds of characters and would want them to have names which are either very significant (see Libatius Borage) or at least sound realistic. A surefire way of doing the latter is using place names (and job titles too as mentioned by others). So, especially for minor characters like Diggle and Runcorn, it is likely to be a reliable strategy to generate a reasonable name.

Answer (score 9):

MuggleNet has extensive listing of the characters that appear in the Harry Potter series.

[Listed here](http://www.mugglenet.com/books/name-origins/), the name in bold comes from a known town while the name parenthesis is just for clarification of character.

However, one can easily see this list is not complete, as two of the name the OP mentions (Dawlish and Runcorn) are not listed. Also, she may used a different origin for their name rather than the town itself. All quotes below come JKR's writings on Pottermore.

1. (Bathilda) **Bagshot** - town in Surrey, England.
2. (Vernon, Petunia, Dudley) **Dursley** - town near J.K. Rowling’s birthplace. *[JKR specifically mentions the town's name as inspiration;](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/vernon-and-petunia-dursley)*

   > The surname ‘Dursley’ was taken from the eponymous town in
   >   Gloucestershire, which is not very far from where I was born. I have
   >   never visited Dursley, and I expect that it is full of charming
   >   people. It was the sound of the word that appealed, rather than any
   >   association with the place.
3. (The Centaur) **Firenze** – Italian name for the city of Florence.
4. Filius **Flitwick** – town in England
5. (Gilderoy) **Lockhart** - town in Australia near Wagga Wagga *[JKR on the origins of Lockhart (note nothing to do with the town)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/gilderoy-lockhart)*

   > I don’t really trawl books. They tend to be things I’ve collected or
   >   stumbled across in general reading. The exception was Gilderoy –
   >   Gilderoy Lockhart. The name Lockhart, well, I know it’s quite a
   >   well-known Scottish surname… …I found on a war memorial. I was looking
   >   for quite a glamorous, dashing sort of surname, and Lockhart caught my
   >   eye on this war memorial, and that was it.
6. **Olympe** (Maxime) - From French. Olympe means “Olympus,” referring to Mount Olympus
7. (Severus) **Snape** - town in England
8. (Sibyll) **Trelawney-** also an area in Cornwall, England. *[JKR states she loves old Cornish surnames](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/sybill-trelawney)* ;

   > I love Cornish surnames, and had never used one until the third book
   >   in the series, so that is how Professor Trelawney got her family name.
   >   I did not want to call her anything comical, or which suggested
   >   chicanery, but something impressive and attractive. 'Trelawney' is a
   >   very old name, suggestive of Sybill's over-reliance on her ancestry
   >   when seeking to impress.

Comment: **Firenze**'s name sounds particularly incongruous to an Italian, as in Italian city names are _feminine_; in the translation, the centaur is named **Fiorenzo**, which preserves the connection to the city name but has a masculine ending.

Comment: For future reference, some other characters are named after constellations.